# Use part of a column in one file as search term in other file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have two files. The output file I am searching has earthquake locations and has the following format:

```
19090212 1323 30.12 36 19.41 103 28.24   7.29   0.00  4 149 25.8 0.02  5.7  9.8 D -         0
19090216 1828 49.61 36 13.27 101 35.38  10.94   0.00 13  54 38.5 0.07  0.3  0.7 B           0
19090711 2114 54.11 35  1.07  99 56.42   7.00   0.00  7 177 18.7 4.00 63.3 53.2 D #         0
```

I want to use the last 6 digits of the first column (i.e. '090418' out of '19090418') with the first 3 digits of the second column (i.e. '072' out of '0728') as my search term. The file I am searching has the following format:

```
SC17 P   090212132329.89
X25A P   090212132330.50

AMTX P   090216182814.12
X29A P   090216182813.70
Y28A P   090216182822.36
MSTX P   090216182826.80
Y27A P   090216182831.43
```

After I search the second file for the term, I need to figure out how many lines are in that section. So for this example, if I were searching the terms shown for the second file above, I want to know there are 2 lines for 090212132 and 5 lines for 090216182.

This is my first post, so please let me know how I can improve clarity or conciseness in my posts. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what have you  tried so far?

Comment: And what is expected outcome?

Comment: Your first file contains no parts from second file. Please fix your example. There is no output at the moment: `grep -f <(cut -b 3-8,10-12 file1) file2`

Comment: you can add input files with some common data elements so that script will have real output.

Comment: Sorry about the file examples not matching. I copied from different parts of the files. The example should make more sense now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[substr($1,3) substr($2,1,3)]; next} 
              {k=substr($3,1,9)} 
        k in a{a[k]++} 
           END{for(k in a) if(a[k]>0) print k,a[k]}' file1 file2
```

with your input files, there is no output as expected.

Comment: I understand some piece of it...like read the file and store the content in array a...extract the second file $3 in k...what is `k in a{a[k]++}`..

Answer (score 0):

The answer karakfa suggested worked! My output looks like this:

```
100224194 7
100117172 18
091004005 11
090520220 10
090526143 21
090122033 20
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! Done. @JayRajput

Answer (score 0):

Karafka answer with explanation

```
awk 'NR==FNR {               # For first file
     $1 = substr($1, 3);     # Get last  6 characters from first col
     $2 = substr($2, 1, 3);  # Get first 3 characters from second col
     a[$1 $2];               # Add to an array
     next }                  # Move to next record in first file

                             # Start processing second file
    {k = substr($3, 1, 9)}   # Get first 9 character for third col
    k in a {a[k]++}          # If key in a, then increment the key

    END {
      for (k in a)           # Iterate array
        if (a[k] > 0)        # If pattern was matched
           print k, a[k]     # print the pattern and num occurrence
    }'
```